# transitionend event not fired in Firefox 15.0.1 under Linux

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, dom-events, css-transitions

This can be tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/rGECn/2/

Is there a workaround for this issue available?

**UPDATE 1:**

`transitionend` in window returns false.

Comment: under Firefox 15.0.1 for Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit it works.

Comment: Maybe if you add the `-moz`? http://jsfiddle.net/rGECn/43/

Comment: The `transition: all 1s;` without vendor prefix works too on FF18 Nightly for Windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: @Ken: I am using FF 15.0.1 under Ubunutu 12.0.4 64-bit/Unity and it is not working for me.

Comment: Updated my comment above, does the `-moz` version of the fiddle works on Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some vendor prefixes in the CSS.

```
button {
    width: 100px;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

According to this [compat table](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions), `transition`s are only supported in IE10 so I'd suggest using jQuery's [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method for a cross-browser solution:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var toggle = [100, 150],
        $this = $(this),
        c = $this.data('count') + 1;
    $this.data('count', c);
    $this.stop(true).animate({'width': toggle[c % toggle.length]}, 1000, function() {
        //done callback
        count();
    });
}).data('count', 0);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rGECn/49/)

Remove the `.stop(true)` if you want to queue up animations instead of breaking them when users click while it is animating.

Comment: Fabicio, looks like the problem is with a buggy library I am using: http://www.paulrhayes.com/2011-11/use-css-transitions-to-link-media-queries-and-javascript/. I have to investigate further. Thanks for the help anyway.